# Adding multiple conditions in a while loop in python

Tags: python, while-loop

i'm having problems adding these 3 conditions in a while loop, where is the error?

```
n = eval(input("Number: "))

i = 0

while (i % 3 == 0) and (i % 5 == 0) and (i < n):
    print(i, end=" ")
    i = i + 1
```

I want it to print the numbers divisible by 3 and 5 as long as i < n.
If i type in 100 it gives back 0 right now.

Comment: Don't use `eval`: you want to parse a strings as an `int` or `float`, not evaluate an arbitrary Python expression.

Comment: Your loop explicitly says to stop when you find the *first* value of `i` that's divisible by 3 and by 5. You are conflating your loop termination condition with your print condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should separate the conditions for division and being less than `n`, making the latter the `while` loop condition, and the former an `if` condition inside the `while` loop, also, you should use `int` instead of `eval` to get the input value as an integer:

```
n = int(input("Number: "))

i = 0

while i < n:
    if (i % 3 == 0) and (i % 5 == 0):
        print(i, end=" ")
    
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: Why use `while`, at all, for what is obviously a range.